# There is a component in android that I can select a range of date weekly, monthly or annually?

Tags: android, datetimepicker

I need a component to select a range of date and time weekly, monthly or annually.

Example:
I have an employee that's come in every Monday and Tuesday at 2pm until 4pm.

A select weekly - Monday, Tuesday 
Time Enter - 2pm 
Time Out - 4 pm

Answer (score 0):

The builtin date picker does not support this. You have two options: implement your own view or use an open source lib. I did some googleing and found 
[A Material design back port of Android's CalendarView](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview).
They write they 
support [four modes of selection: single, multiple, range or none](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview/blob/master/docs/CUSTOMIZATION.md#date-selection). Please note: I have not tried the library and I am not involved in this project.

Comment: I found one [MaterialDateRangePicker](https://github.com/borax12/MaterialDateRangePicker) but isn't exactly that I need. I'll implement my own view.